# Asking question on main site requesting links to online sources?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have great difficulty trying to find online sources in developing plugins for QGIS. Which is why I would like to ask on the main site for possible links to such sources. However, I am aware that in a number of SE forums, this type of question *can* be frowned upon.

**Can I ask on the main site for links to online sources?**

Or does it perhaps need to be a **Community Wiki** question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asking for links to online sources is something that I think is frowned upon at our Main site too.  From the sounds of it I know that I am very likely to vote to close such a post for being too broad.

If you are having difficulty developing plugins for QGIS, then you could ask questions on Main about those specific difficulties, because such focussed Q&A is always welcome.

If anyone reads your focussed questions there and knows an online source that might short circuit future similar questions then I am sure that they will mention it in a comment or answer.

The GIS Chat Room is the only part of GIS SE where I think asking for links to sources is OK to do, but I think asking focussed Q&A questions on Main offers a better chance of uncovering what you are after.

Comment: Thanks for answering, you make a fair and valid point! =)